# Dropdown menu drops the options down when clicking

Tags: jquery, css

I have a dropdown menu with 4 links, and when I click on one of them, the rest of the menu gets dropped down.

The HTML Code is:

```
<div class="dropdown-graus dropdown-element">
<div class="dropdown-graus-button dropdown-button">GRADES</div>

<div class="dropdown-graus-content">

<div class="dropdown-graus-facultat-1 dropdown-facultad">
<div class="facultat-1-name">LABEL 1</div>
<div class="facultat-1-view">VIEW 1</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-graus-facultat-2 dropdown-facultad">
<div class="facultat-2-name">LABEL 2</div>
<div class="facultat-2-view">VIEW 2</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-graus-facultat-3 dropdown-facultad">
<div class="facultat-3-name">LABEL 3</div>
<div class="facultat-3-view">VIEW 3</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-masters dropdown-element">
<div class="dropdown-masters-button dropdown-button">MASTERS</div>
<div class="dropdown-masters-content"></div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-futurs dropdown-element">
<div class="dropdown-futurs-button dropdown-button">FUTURE</div>
<div class="dropdown-futurs-content"></div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-coneix dropdown-element">
<div class="dropdown-coneix-button dropdown-button">CONTACT</div>
<div class="dropdown-coneix-content"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.dropdown-graus-content {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f0f0f1;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

.dropdown-masters-content {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-futurs-content {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-coneix-content {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-button {
    float: left;
    padding: 0.312em 0.625em;
}

.dropdown-button {
    padding: 0.312em 0.625em 0.312em 0em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.dropdown-facultad {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 300px;
}

.dropdown-graus-facultat-1 {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.dropdown-graus-facultat-2 {
    margin: 0px 5px;
}

.dropdown-graus-facultat-3 {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/9wDgL/

If you click on GRADES, you will see how the menu gets pushed down. The content display with the onClick() must be relative because the rest of the content has to be pushed down.

I've done this many times, but I can't find why it's not working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap the order of the `div`s, so that all the dropdown content comes *after* all the menu items:

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wDgL/4/)

```
    <!-- menu items -->
    <div class="dropdown-graus dropdown-element">
        <div class="dropdown-graus-button dropdown-button">GRAUS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-masters dropdown-element">
        <div class="dropdown-masters-button dropdown-button">MASTERS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-futurs dropdown-element">
        <div class="dropdown-futurs-button dropdown-button">FUTURE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-coneix dropdown-element">
        <div class="dropdown-coneix-button dropdown-button">CONTACT</div>
    </div>

    <!-- dropdown content -->
    <div class="dropdown-graus-content">
        <div class="dropdown-graus-facultat-1 dropdown-facultad">
            <div class="facultat-1-name">LABEL 1</div>
            <div class="facultat-1-view">VIEW 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-graus-facultat-2 dropdown-facultad">
            <div class="facultat-2-name">LABEL 2</div>
            <div class="facultat-2-view">VIEW 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-graus-facultat-3 dropdown-facultad">
            <div class="facultat-3-name">LABEL 3</div>
            <div class="facultat-3-view">VIEW 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-masters-content"></div>
    <div class="dropdown-futurs-content"></div>
    <div class="dropdown-coneix-content"></div>
</div>
```